# Why doesn't failure handling work in Spring Security X.509 authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a custom-filter with an X509 filter (subclass of `X509AuthenticationFilter`). The X509 filter's only job is to pull the certificate out of the request. I have a corresponding `AuthenticationProvider` that throws a `BadCredentialsException` if the credentials are invalid. My intention is that when the `AuthenticationProvider` throws `BadCredentialsException` that the `BadCredentialsException` causes the request to be forwarded to `message.jsp`. However, it does not do so. When debugging, I noticed that the Exception is thrown, caught, and stored under WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION... but none of the other Spring Security classes seem to utilize the Exception, and I cannot find any way to use a failure handler.

```
<security:http auto-config="false" pattern="/role/**" access-decision-manager-ref="adm" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
        <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/message.jsp"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="authFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
</security:http>

<bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="..." />

<bean id="authFilter" class="...">
   <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
   <property name="continueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication" value="false" />
</bean>
```

I've tried both PRE_AUTH and X509 filter options for `authFilter`. I've also tried `authFilter` with and without the `continueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication` option. Neither makes any difference and errors are not handled by spring security.

**What I want is:**

A way to do X509 authentication with error handling provided by the spring security framework. I don't care if it is considered "pre auth" or not, although I think Spring Security might require the filter to be placed in either the pre auth or X509 position. I would like tips on how to get this working or specifics on what to look at.

Comment: All, Abraham's answer below does work, but this issue will be officially fixed soon in the 4.1 release, please see the Spring Security team's ticket https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3389.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally in Spring Security, redirecting to a page due to an uncaught `AuthenticationException` (which `BadCredentialsException` extends) works as follows:

1. A `FilterSecurityInterceptor` throws an `AuthenticationException`.
2. The `AuthenticationException` is caught by an `ExceptionTranslationFilter`.
3. The `ExceptionTranslationFilter` sends the request to the `entry-point-ref` to be authenticated.

This cycle of events takes place near the [end of the filter chain](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-stack).  Your custom `X509AuthenticationFilter` and `AuthenticationProvider`, however, are validating the certificate much earlier in the chain.  To get failed certificate validations to redirect, do the following:

1. Have your `AuthenticationManager`/`AuthenticationProvider` throw a `BadCredentialsException`, as you are currently doing.
2. Allow your custom `X509AuthenticationFilter` to null out the the `Authentication` associated with the request (which should be its inherited behavior from `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`).
3. Install a separate `FilterSecurityInterceptor` later in the chain that throws an `AuthenticationException` for requests without an `Authentication`, which will result in the request being sent to the entry point.

This can be done as follows:

```
<security:http auto-config="false" pattern="/role/**" entry-point-ref="failureMessageEntryPoint">
    <security:anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="authFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/> <!-- authenticationManager will throw a BadCredentialsException, resulting in a null Authentication for the request -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/role/**" access="isAuthenticated"/> <!-- will reject requests with a null Authentication by throwing an AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException -->
                                                                          <!-- AuthenticationExceptions will be caught by auto-configured ExceptionTranslationFilter, and sent to entry point -->
</security:http>

<bean id="failureMessageEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"> <!-- not actually for login, but will work as an entry point that redirects to a page -->
    <constructor-arg value="/message.jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authFilter" class="...">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <!-- let continueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication default to true to allow the intercept-url to reject the request -->
</bean>
```

Comment: Two related questions for you. The Spring Security section on filter ordering (http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-ordering) says ExceptionTranslationFilter should be after "authentication processing mechanisms". Doesn't that contradict your answer? Second question: the spring tutorial says to use http403EntryPoint. But the http403EntryPoint never actually gets called in the case of AuthenticationException (or at all, for that matter). Would you agree the http403EntryPoint is not needed?

Comment: I agree the `http403EntryPoint` is not needed.  It's just a placeholder entry point because typically for X509 certificates, the authentication has already taken place outside of Spring Security, so there is no entry point for authentication.  And yeah, having an auth mechanism after the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` is a bit hacky.  I've amended my answer to leave the auth mechanism before the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and use a separate filter for enforcing the redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out responses. I like this approach. The piece I was missing was that an intercept-url will throw an AuthenticationException if there is a NULL authentication principal. It seems like an odd design choice by Spring Security team that the FilterSecurityInterceptor ignores the previous Exception that was caught by the AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter in the unsuccessfulAuthentication method and stored under the WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION key.

Comment: Agreed, it would be a more sensible default behavior to have an automatic failure somewhere in the chain when `WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION` is not null.

Comment: Marking as accepted answer. One last note is that the access="isAuthenticated" level will require the user principal's granted authorities to contain that granted authority. Then the access decision manager will accept the user principal as authenticated, but if an AuthenticationException was thrown, you'll be forwarded to the desired page as stated in this answer. Thanks again!